# Get SamAccountName from Windowsidentity.Groups for users is slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap

Getting the list of SamAccountId's for GROUPS for a batch of users is very slow using:

```
    public List<ADUserDTO> GetListDomainUsers(string domain)
    {
        var myDomainUsers = new List<ADUserDTO>();
        using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            var userPrinciple = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
            using (var search = new PrincipalSearcher(userPrinciple))
            {
                foreach (UserPrincipal domainUser in search.FindAll().OrderBy(u => u.DisplayName))
                {
                    if (domainUser.Enabled.Value)
                    {
                        var adUser = new ADUserDTO()
                        {
                            Description = domainUser.Description,
                            DisplayName = domainUser.DisplayName,
                            DistinguishedName = domainUser.DistinguishedName,
                            EmailAddress = domainUser.EmailAddress,
                            Name = domainUser.Name,
                            EmployeeId = domainUser.EmployeeId,
                            GivenName = domainUser.GivenName,
                            MiddleName = domainUser.MiddleName,
                            Surname = domainUser.Surname,
                            SamAccountName = domainUser.SamAccountName,
                            Groups = new List<string>()
                        };
                        // groups:
                        var groups = GetGroups(adUser.SamAccountName);
                        if (groups.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var group in groups)
                            {
                                adUser.Groups.Add(group);
                            }
                        }
                        myDomainUsers.Add(adUser);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return myDomainUsers;
    }

        public List<string> GetGroups(string userName)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(userName);
        foreach (IdentityReference group in wi.Groups)
        {
            try
            {
                var directoryEntry = returnObjectBydSid(group.Value.ToString());
                var props = directoryEntry.Properties;                  
                var name = props["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();
                result.Add(name);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

1. Can this be done faster?
2. why does this produce a Exception
   thrown: 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException' in
   System.DirectoryServices.dll

Comment: Just to be clear, that function is written in C#?

Comment: yeps a netcore program in c#